# Transaction, set isolation level

Tags: mysql, transactions

I have been reading about setting the isolation levels of transactions. But couldn't really find a straight answer to the simple question:

Do I first set the isolation level and then start the transaction or vice versa.

```
START TRANSACTION
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ COMMITTED
```

So which command comes first? Does it even matter?

PS: Is there any disadvantage about using transactions/isolation levels for PHP/MySQL sites?

Comment: PS: I read that transactions might not even work when you have the MyISAM engine?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should set the transaction level first:

```
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ COMMITTED;
START TRANSACTION;
```

as you can't change the isolation level from within a transaction.

In fact, attempting to is the only way to tell if you're inside a transaction with certain versions of MySQL.